# Update php config for Web App on Azure

Tags: php, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have created a php web app on azure portal. I can't upload any file which has more than 8 MB size. How can I update the maximum file size for the php configs (i.e. `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size`) on azure web app? I can't find any thing to change the php config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should update `web.config` in the root of the project. To do this you can go to the kudu console using the following link:

`https://<name of your website>.scm.azurewebsites.net/debugconsole`

after adding the `web.config` you can edit the file using the edit button next to the created file.

[image]

After that you should edit the file like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="<valueInBytes>"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As your project is in php (it does not matter is CMS or pure php code), you should add a file which is dubbed `.user.ini` such as follow. First go to the Kudu console as referenced above. The run the following command to create the user file:

```
touch .user.ini
```

[image]

by running the above command, the file is created and you can edit it like the `web.config`. In this file, you should put the following configs:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

Definitely, you can change the size of the upload and post max size in the above config. after saving the file you must restart the site to everything works fine. To do this. go to the azure portal, select your website, and click on the restart button.

[image]

You can upload the interested file from now on! thanks to [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/06/15/uploading-large-files-to-azure-web-apps/).