# Azure web app: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

For a university project we are using Azure to function as an API backend to a website hosted on Github Pages. The Azure server has recently stopped functioning, giving the error **"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable"**.
The web.conf file was not changed, other than a couple of new php files nothing was, and the server was functioning for a while after these files were uploaded.
We have tried restarting and redeploying the server, which fixes the problem but only for a couple of minutes.
The web.conf file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="allToIndex" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^((?!css).)*$"/>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check if below steps helps to:**

- Make sure the `web.config` is placed in the root folder of the website.
- Make Sure you allow your IP address in the `web.config` file like below:

```php
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
            <add allowed="true" ipAddress="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" />
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- Sometimes, the `web.config` is missed in the Azure Portal Web application Folder. If missed, In the Kudu (the backend for Web Apps) will create a `Web.config` for you. So you go to `<your_site>.scm.azurewebsites.net` and use the file browser, you'll find the `web.config` that's automatically generated if you don't specify one.
- Check the Configuration Settings once by traversing to ***Azure Portal > App Service > Settings > Configuration > General Settings > <check the stack and PHP version - update as per requirement>*** and then Click ***Save***, ***Restart*** the applied changes in Configuration and also the ***App Service***.
- If you're uploading any files to the existing PHP Web Application Azure, then please check this [reference related to updating web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814104/update-php-config-for-web-app-on-azure).

**Also Please check the below references related to the specific error of PHP Web App in Azure called `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`**

1. [MSFT Q& A related thread to resource temporarily unavailable/removed/name changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/588188/the-resource-you-are-looking-for-has-been-removed-1.html)
2. [Article 1](http://lifestyleandcoding.blogspot.com/2018/07/the-resource-you-are-looking-for-has.html)
3. [A GitHub Page of the above specified error resolution](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azureappservice/issues/395)